# How to automate PHP 7 installation on Ubuntu 16.04 in Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, php, docker

I am trying to create a Dockerfile to install PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04. This is supposed to fully automate the whole installation process. However, during the installation, it prompts me to select a Geographic area, which completely defeats the purpose.

The directive I am using is:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php
```

And here is the prompt:

[image]

How can I automate this? Maybe prepare some predefined values for the prompts in some manner?

Note: I am aware of this image link: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/. Unfortunately, the scripts there are overly complicated for me. I just need something nice and simple.

Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using for the installation?

Comment: running `docker run php` is too complicated? and that's why you want to build your own docker image? okay ...

Comment: No. You misunderstood. I meant the scripts in the Docker file links are too complicated. Follow this link and see for yourself: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/85af0c14e3f23689f0851d3164ab3b630e7f016f/7.2/stretch/cli/Dockerfile.

Comment: 200+ lines of Dockerfile for installing PHP is overly complicated, for my task at hand (not going into details here) at the moment.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce your problem. `apt install -y php` installs php without further questions.

Comment: Hence I said "scripts", not the command.

Comment: Probably due to that we are using different distros.

Comment: I've set up an ubuntu 16.04 for the test. installed all current updates. ran `sudo apt install -y php`. It went through without asking about a geographic location.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, sir. I am not sure why it happened on my machine. Posted a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out tzdata is it. The solution in this link works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331836/apt-get-install-tzdata-noninteractive.

Comment: This question even has an example with a docker example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671308/non-interactive-method-for-dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata/47909037#47909037

Comment: If you had posted that you have a problem with tzdata instead of php in the first place we could have solved this a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, you are right :)